# PHP/Javascript: Pass simple string defining which section to include

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

My website is split into 4 divs: header, navigation, content, footer.
There are 6 content sections: home, downloads, skills, practice, projects and about.

Inside navigation I have a menu that has linked button for each section.

Edit: I want to know how or what to use to pass data from one php file to another without using a form.

Comment: OK. What is the question?

Comment: Clearly there is a language barrier, but its really hard to understand exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: I am sorry, I was writting this one in a bus.
I wanted to know how or what to use to pass a data from one php file to another without using a form.

Comment: You need JS and maybe a splash of Ajax for this if you want. This is a bit too broad a question though.

Comment: Can't it be done without Ajax, I'd rather use code I can later modify.

Comment: Sure, you can go without Ajax. You need an JS onchange listener for sure.

Comment: *Edit: I want to know how or what to use to pass data from one php file to another without using a form.* - What kind of data are we talking and for what use, a database?

Comment: I already found a solution.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.

Comment: You can do it without a form hand crafting the urls to contain the params you want to pass. But IMO you should at least use forms.

Comment: I'll pass data via <a href="index.php?section=downloads">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" name="section-filename-here">Item</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Where you see name="section-filename-here", only input the name of the file without the .php extension as this can be added in the jQuery as in the example below

Javascript (jQuery/aJax):

```
$('ul.nav li a').click(function () {
    var thisSection = $(this).attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path-to-sections/"+thisSection+".php",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            // only put something here if you want to show an error
        }
    });
});
```